# Elastic Search Document not in json format

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Im very new to Elastic Search, Logstash and kibana so bear with me. So I'm trying to create a document and store it into the index on the elastic search pipeline. I created an ingest pipeline, added an index with the mappings and then added a data view which grabs that index. Im able to use the Elastic client to upload documents but Im noticing that the document isnt in a json format.
Its looking like this for my documents in my  discover tab in my data view on kibana:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSLcL.png

I'd like it to be in a json format instead:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LulFP.png

Here's my code:

```
import * as Elastic from '@elastic/elasticsearch';

const client = new Elastic.Client({
   cloud: {
     id: "cloudID here",
   },
   auth: {                
     apiKey: "apikey here",
   },
});

const testData = 
   {                
     id: "pwe23",
     description: "apple",
     time: 1668146556,                           
     payload: {
       uid: "test",
       status: "success",
       trxId: '33',
   }
}
      

const res = await client.ping();

const indexRes = await client.index({
  index: 'test_index',                        
  body: { time: testData.time, testData },
  pipeline: 'test_pipeline',
})

// I tried just passing in as body: testData directly as well but no luck


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LulFP.png
```

Comment: The whole point of Elasticsearch is to index those fields.
You can still reteive your documents in json, but you can also now search by fields.
I am not sure why you would like to have a raw json in elasticsearch

Comment: Well, this is more of a logging function because different apis have different payloads. I'd only want to index a few important fields like the ids but most of the payload is just for reference hence the raw json